# C# & ASP.NET MVC - saving changes to database doesn't save

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, ssms

I'm trying to edit some data in my database using two functions. The first function works, but every time I try the second one, it doesn't actually save the changes into the database.

Would anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

The examples are in different classes, but I think that this should be enough information:

PcController.cs

```
    public ActionResult PokemonSteps(int id, int steps)
    {
        var user = _userRepo.getUser(User.Identity.Name);
            _userPokemonRepo.walkPokemon(id, steps, user); //<-- doesn't work
            _userRepo.takeSteps(user, steps); //<-- does work

            return RedirectToAction("Pokemon", new { id });
    }
```

UserPokemonRepo.cs

```
    public void walkPokemon(int id, int steps, USER user)
    {
        //get the pokemon data that needs to be edited
        var pokemon = new UserPokemonRepo().getPokemon(id);

        //make sure the pokemon belongs to the trainer, and has enough steps
        if (pokemon.CTid == user.Id)
        {
            if (user.Steps < steps)
            {
                steps = user.Steps.Value;
            }

            var maxExp = getMaxExp(pokemon.POKEMON_DATA.EXP_RATIO.ExpRatio);

            if (pokemon.Experience + steps > maxExp)
            {
                steps = maxExp - pokemon.Experience;
            }

            addExperience(pokemon, steps);
            addHappiness(pokemon, steps / 2500);
        }
    }

    public void addExperience(USER_POKEMON pokemon, int steps)
    {
        //add experience to the pokemon
        pokemon.Experience += steps;

        var maxExp = getMaxExp(pokemon.POKEMON_DATA.EXP_RATIO.ExpRatio);

        if (pokemon.Experience > maxExp)
        {
            pokemon.Experience = maxExp;
        }

        //save to the database
        PDCEntities.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void addHappiness(USER_POKEMON pokemon, int happiness)
    {
        //add happiness to the pokemon
        pokemon.Happiness += (happiness);

        if (pokemon.Happiness > Constants.MAXHAPPINESS)
        {
            pokemon.Happiness = Constants.MAXHAPPINESS;
        }

        //save to the database
        PDCEntities.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I've stepped through it in the debugger and the values do change - I'm assuming it's something to do with my functions and how they are nested?

The `_userRepo.takeSteps(user, steps)` does this, in the `userRepo.cs`, and it works fine

```
    public void takeSteps(USER user, int steps)
    {
        user.Steps -= steps;
        PDCEntities.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: `<add name="PokemonDayCare2Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.PDCModel.csdl|res://*/Entities.PDCModel.ssdl|res://*/Entities.PDCModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-O2J8D;initial catalog=PokemonDayCare2;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />` this is it right? I don't think it has the clause, I guess

Comment: Why does some code use `_userPokemonRepo` and some use `new UserPokemonRepo()`?

Comment: they're in separate classes, I'm trying to use some Structure Map Dependency Scope thing but it only works in Controllers for me for some reason, so the first function is in a Controller class and the others are in the actual Repo

Comment: What does PDCEntities.SaveChanges() do? How is that using the userPokemonRepo to write the changes to your database?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. There are literally hundreds of reasons why this could occur - and we need a simple example to narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: @SimplyGed `saveChanges()` is what saves the changes I've made to the data into the database. `userPokemonRepo` is the repository that makes the changes to the database data. ` var pokemon = new UserPokemonRepo().getPokemon(id);` gets the field of data from the database, and the rest of the code changes it. I don't know if I'm being very helpful, I'll update my post with comments

Comment: I'm no EF expert but I think it is because you haven't added the pokemon to `PDCEntitites`. If it is not tracked it won't insert, update or delete.

Comment: I think I get what you're trying to say, but I don't think I've had to do that before... If you look at the `takeSteps()` I edited in a second ago I don't track it but those changes still save each time

Comment: I won't hear you unless you address me with @<username>... But, the implementation of `takeSteps()` is not enough info, what is important is how you acquired the `user` that you passed to it. If you queried the context for it then it is tracked.

Comment: @<Crowcoder> Ah, I'm getting the user through the `_userRepo.getUser(User.Identity.Name);` which is just one line `return PDCEntities.USERs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == username);` so I guess that query tracks it? I get the pokemon in pretty much the same manner (I think), via `UserPokemonRepo().getPokemon(id);` which is also one line `return PDCEntities.USER_POKEMON.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);` - so my understanding is that it would be tracked there?

Comment: @mint , I didn't mean include the "<>". Anyway, to my knowledge that should work. Are you sure the code is entering the `if` block?

Comment: @Crowcoder It definitely does - it stops on the breakpoints and it even changes the values before the save line

Comment: @mint my last guess is that `PDCEntities` is not the same context instance as the context in your repo that returned the pokemon.

Comment: @Crowcoder that sounds like it probably is it... it wouldn't be the changes are taking too long so the database reaches the save code before the changes are made?

Comment: @Crowcoder you were right! I was making a new context/instance/whatever with the line `var pokemon = new UserPokemonRepo().getPokemon(id);` and changed it to `var pokemon = .getPokemon(id);` and it works... i feel a little dumb, thank you so much for your help!